# PHP - Steam Market JSON Returning "null" - Working Fine Before

Tags: php, null, web-scraping, steam, steam-web-api

Ok, so I run a website which essentially in its core steam market prices. The way i pull the prices is through the steam market json form, which uses the market hash name and returns the price data i need: http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=730&currency=1&market_hash_name=MP7%20|%20Skulls%20(Minimal%20Wear)
Now, this system was working fine, and the link on my computer works fine; however, when i run it off my server, it returns just "null" - This is the code im using that used to work fine (6+ months) and stopped working sometime this week.

```
    <?php

    function curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,  '');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
    }

    $url = "http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=730&currency=1&market_hash_name=MP7%20|%20Skulls%20(Minimal%20Wear)";
    $data = curl($url);
    echo $data;

    ?>
```

Any ideas as to what has changed? I make 2300+ requests every 30 minutes in refreshing my data. Every day for the past like 6 months. Could Valve noticed and shut me off for violating some terms I didn't know about? Because I believed this was the way you were supposed to request data from the steam market.

Comment: works fine for me m8, your server might be blocked